# Non-alphabetic Delimiters

Tags: c, linux, string, unix, delimiter

I'm trying to parse a string into *only* alphabetic letters, so all punctuation, numbers, symbols, etc., get treated as delimiters. Here's my problem: there are a *lot* of non-letter characters to delimit.

Is there a way to filter **all** such characters? I mean there are 26 standard English letters and 52 if you count caps. I know ASCII/Unicode don't really work this way, but it would seem like there should be some kind of exclusivity method, as in I could provide all the characters I want to allow and establish everything else in the ASCII/Unicode tables as a delimiter.

So I guess I'm asking, is something like this possible? Can you isolate everything outside the ranges 65-90 and 97-122 (Unicode)?

I'm currently using this as my delimiter string, and while it captures probably 95% of the characters that would need to be caught, I'd like something more substantial:

```
#define DELIMITERS " 0123456789<>?:,./;'[]{}-=_+\\\""
```

Comment: I think doing it the way you have is asking for trouble.  You'd be substituting in a single double quotation mark all over your code?  That's got to be bad?

Comment: i wouldnt try that in c it will take too long to code, translate in unix would be a safer option , easy and fast .....  tr -c '0123456789<>?:,./;'[]{}-=_+\\\' should help !!

Answer (score 1):

The stock way to do this would be with a [**regular expression**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), say `[^a-zA-Z]+`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way -- use isalpha()  from ctype.h

```
char ok[80]={0x0};  // 80 bytes max
char *p=input_str;
char *q=ok;
for(*q=0x0; *p; p++)
{
    if( isalpha((int)*p) )
    {
        *q=*p;
        q++;
        *q=0x0;
    }
}
printf("%s\n", ok);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your input data looks like and how you implemented your parser. I assume you're currently using something along the lines of `strsep()`, for which your current approach is sound (but not a complete list of non-alphabetic characters, see e.g. `#`, `$`, `%`).

If you write your own tokenization function (or if you want to build up the delimiter string programmatically), then take a look at `isalpha()` and `iswalpha()` in `ctype.h`/`wctype.h`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) you can find the documentation for regex.h. It is a regular expressions library for C.

Take the time to learn [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and you'll find that this problem can be solved very easily ;).